# Java XML XPath Parser to C#

Tags: c#, java, xml, parsing, xpath

I am currently porting a Java-written XML parser to C#. The parser in Java was written by me a couple months ago (though now largely abandoned since our compnay moved to C# for our projects) which parsed XML data via a URL, in particular, [this](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=NDFDgen&lat=37.7833&lon=-122.4167&listLatLon=&lat1=&lon1=&lat2=&lon2=&resolutionSub=&listLat1=&listLon1=&listLat2=&listLon2=&resolutionList=&endPoint1Lat=&endPoint1Lon=&endPoint2Lat=&endPoint2Lon=&listEndPoint1Lat=&listEndPoint1Lon=&listEndPoint2Lat=&listEndPoint2Lon=&zipCodeList=&listZipCodeList=&centerPointLat=&centerPointLon=&distanceLat=&distanceLon=&resolutionSquare=&listCenterPointLat=&listCenterPointLon=&listDistanceLat=&listDistanceLon=&listResolutionSquare=&citiesLevel=&listCitiesLevel=&sector=&gmlListLatLon=&featureType=&requestedTime=&startTime=&endTime=&compType=&propertyName=&product=time-series&begin=2014-03-09&end=2014-03-15&Unit=m&maxt=maxt&mint=mint&temp=temp&dew=dew&wspd=wspd&rh=rh&Submit=Submit) (with custom lat/long/time parameters).

For the Java parser, I chose XPath as the data was sorta.. messy. So defining my custom paths instead of iterating and saving every single item was what I did.

Code snippet in Java in question I am having some issues porting over is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(someURLToXML.openStream());

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

XPathExpression hourly = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/time-layout[3]/start-valid-time/text()");
XPathExpression tempHourly = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='hourly']/value/text()");

NodeList hourlyResult = (NodeList) hourly.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList tempHourlyResult = (NodeList) tempHourly.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Reading some tutorials on C# XPath scripting, I came across this [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C). Upon additionally Googling it seems this is the de facto way to do XPath on C#.

I have this so far in my C# skeleton:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URL);

XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

XPathExpression expr;
expr = nav.Compile("/dwml/data/");
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

while (iterator.MoveNext())
{ 
    // do something
}
```

What I have done is I determined my default expressions at `expr`, but after that, I'm not quite sure how to port my above `XPaths` from the Java script to within the `While` loop, or even if I need it, since my original script didn't use any loops at all, since there was no need with the hardcoding of the XML traversal.

My question is, how do I port the four lines:

```
XPathExpression hourly = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/time-layout[3]/start-valid-time/text()");
XPathExpression tempHourly = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='hourly']/value/text()");

NodeList hourlyResult = (NodeList) hourly.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList tempHourlyResult = (NodeList) tempHourly.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

To C#?

***EDIT:***

Trying this:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URL);

XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

foreach(XPathNavigator node in (XPathNodeIterator) nav.Evaluate("/dwml/data/time-layout[3]/start-valid-time/text()"))
{
    hourly.Add(node.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below allowed me to retain my XPath rules and still do what I want, and on the plus side, it adds the values to a string list -- nice!

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URL);

XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

List<string> hourly = new List<string>();

foreach(XPathNavigator node in (XPathNodeIterator) nav.Evaluate("/dwml/data/time-layout[3]/start-valid-time/text()"))
{
    hourly.Add(node.Value);
}
```

Comment: funny you are self-complimenting :)

Comment: The following blog post from Microsoft's XML Team states that `XmlTextReader` is obsolete and should not be used.  `XmlReader` should be used instead.  The blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2011/10/08/the-world-has-moved-on-have-you-xml-apis-you-should-avoid-using/